# Oracle reports 11g using wrong font when producing multi page report

Tags: oracle, fonts, oraclereports

We have a very strange problem, and I am not even sure this is the right place to ask this, but we have just moved to Oracle Reports 11g from 10g and when we run a report in PDF format that produces more than one page the wrong font is used in certain places.

It is only in certain fields of the report (in a line for subtotals for instance) rather than the whole page.

If we run the same report to create a single page (single record returned) the fonts are fine.

If we produce an RTF version of the report we get the same effect but it uses a completely different font from the PDF version(in the test we ran it actually decide to choose wingdings as its font).

If the report is run using the local PC client the problem goes away, it only manifests itself when running this on the report server itself.

The only font the report asks to use is standard Arial.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? Is there anything on the server we can check?

Comment: Are both the client and server machines running the same OS?

Comment: Also - you say you're just using Arial, but are the sizes different on the offending fields (e.g. bad fields might use Arial 8 pt,  everything else uses Arial 10 pt)?

Comment: Hi Bob, The clients are windows, the server is linux. The only difference is that the font in the affected fields is Bold. The point size is the same

Comment: I don't know anything about Oracle Reports, but I suspect there's some kind of font mapping mechanism that's gotten messed up by the upgrade to 11g.  Hunt around and see if you can find anything about font handling in Oracle Reports.  Good luck.

Comment: Turns out that this was a "known issue" with Oracle Reports and applying Patch 10229867 fixed this for us.